# Details for how Anthos Migrate works

Tags: migrate, google-anthos

Trying to get more details specific to the Anthos Migrate process.    Specifically, when it analyzes a VM, it is going to find the OS and then say the Runtime - for this question lets assume it finds Tomcat 8.0

Does Migrate take the Tomcat that is contained within that Image and use that content as the Source for when the Dockerfile runs - or - does it say - We have found a GCP provided Tomcat image that will be used as the "base" image for this application ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Migrate take the Tomcat that is contained within that Image and use that content as the Source for when the Dockerfile runs

Yes, that's what it does.

Since you mention Docker, I assume you're interested in the migration from a VM to Kubernetes. In this scenario the kernel is supplied by the Kubernetes node, but the rest of the image of your VM is left mostly intact.